# Codeigniter routes regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes

I have this:

```
$route['^[a-zA-Z]{2}$'] = "state";

$route['^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/(:any)'] = "state/city";
```

And these controllers

**state.php**

```
class State extends CI_Controller {

    public function index () 
    {
        echo "OK"; 
    } 
    public function city () 
    {
       echo "Not OK"; 
    } 
}
```

The first route works perfectly, while the second does not. She should call the city of the State class method but does not call!

url:

> http://foo.bar/SP/ ---> OK
>   http://foo.bar/SP/SANTOS -> 404!

Comment: You **also** need to catch the the wildcard **(:any)** with **$1** and pass it to your controller/method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `$` that anchors to the end of the string:

```
$route['^[a-zA-Z]{2}/(:any)'] = "state/city";
```